How to shrink the MacOS menu bar by height
The screen in my MB Pro 16 2023 needed to be replaced. When I got my mac back, the MacOS 14.5 menu bar was half its normal size, as in the pic. It was a bit puzzling but I liked it, since it made the usable part of my screen larger. Unfortunately, the menu bar went back to its normal size (going around the notch) after a restart. How can I shrink it back?


You can manually kill the WindowManager on macOS to get the "broken" status bar back.
Execute the following:
sudo killall -HUP WindowServer
⚠️ Beware that your MacBook will soft restart when doing that though.

There is an option in System Settings > Accessibility > Displays to set the size of the text in the menubar; but not the size of the menu itself.
I can only guess that this was some anomaly of an incorrect screen size or scaling after the screen replacement, which was then corrected after a restart.
You could try changing the display scaling towards "More Space", to see if that gives you the effect you're looking for.
